# Move a SQL 2000 32-bit database

Tags: sql-server-2005, 32bit-64bit

Can I move a SQL 2000 32-bit database to a SQL 2005 64-bit database server

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can. There are two easy ways to do this:

1. Create a backup of the database and restore it on the new server.
2. Detach the database and then move the .mdf and .ldf to the new server and attach them to to it.

I prefer to use the backup method since as the name implies, you're working with a backup of the data so it's relatively low risk.

Answer (score 1):

You should also test that your Applications that use those Databases work once you move it over (Backup method is best way to go).

If any of the applications fail you may need to look into using compatibility mode which you can set in the Database Properties, I would suggest making a list of all applications and then doing test first to be sure that nothing plays up.

Comment: Good point. The databases will move over without a problem but it may cause unexpected issues with any programs that only work with 32-bit software. Always a good idea to test for any potential problems before committing to the change.

Answer (score 0):

32 bit to 64bit should not matter.

The procedure is actually fairly straight forward.

Here is a tutorial that explains it step by step

http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/MS-SQL-Server/Moving-Data-from-SQL-Server-2000-to-SQL-Server-2005/

Take care and good luck

HTH